# Global soft validation for multiple registation forms in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I've created my website registration functionality using six different steps with different forms..now i want to create 
global soft validation for all six steps..

suppose i am new website user..now i clicked on directly registration step 3 then i can able to go directly step 3 without
enterting information for step 1 and step 2..now suppose clicked on previous step from step 3 then i want one global validation array for step1 and step 2..
which will be display on step 2 form when i clicked on previos step from step 3..

If any one have idea about then please let me know ASAP..

Comment: Could you try and reword your question? Do you mean you want to be able to validate each step as you go, one step at a time, rather than validate all steps at the last step?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at the 'validating data from the controller' chapter. You have to write some logic and checks to see which steps/fields been set:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html